# Entity Framework - Multiple classes (tables) of the same interface - DbSet exposure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public interface IQuestion {
    // A couple of common properties go here, like Name, etc
}

/* Now follows multiple implementations of my interface, each of which has some custom properties */

public class TextBoxQuestion: IQuestion {
  public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}

public class DateQuestion: IQuestion {
  public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }
}


public class MyRepo : DbContext {
 **public DbSet<IQuestion> { get; set; } // Problem**
}
```

How would I go about implementing my DbContext? I can't expose an interface, as EF requires concrete implementations, which of course make sense, given the fact that I also have to generate a database.

Should I be exposing every IQuestion implementation I have, in the DbContext?

What is a better design - one huge table with all possible properties + discriminator column, or separate table for each implementation?

Edit:

I have added

```
public class BaseQuestion : IQuestion {
    // Implements the common properties, plus:
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and changed the Context to:

```
public class MyRepo : DbContext {
     public DbSet<BaseQuestion> { get; set; }
}
```

EF now generates a 'huge table' + Discriminator column for me. The table 'automatically' includes the properties of all classes in my solution, which inherit the BaseQuestion. Is this the best practice?

Comment: using generics:  public class MyRepo<T> : DbContext where T : BaseQuestion
    {
        public DbSet<T> Question {get;set;}
    }   samles: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte

Comment: actually I'm not interested in pulling questions out of the db. They will be parented by another object, let's call it 'Quiz'. I only care about their persistence and proper indirect retrieval (i.e. when I query for a Quiz). I only add the BaseQuestion to the DbContext, because I want it to be part of the database generation. Now that I think about it, it doesn't even have to be in the DbContext, it will still get generated as a table, even if it's just a property of my Quiz. Anyway, the key to the whole thing was to use a Base class, instead of an interface.

Comment: Is Quiz class  something that will has a table in db and what is relationship between quiz and questions 1-n.

Comment: 1 quiz to Many questions. Quiz is persisted, yes.